# How to get CMYK value for a given PMS value?

Tags: colors, rgb, cmyk

I have a PMS(Pantone Matching System) color value. I need to find the corresponding CMYK(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK) or RGB values for that PMS value.

Any links that cite the conversion or a color chart would help.

cheers

Comment: Something to keep in mind is that, if you're referring to a specific PMS color, it usually can't be matched in CMYK (or RGB). (In other words, PMS 286 is a lovely blue that can't be precisely matched in four-color process).  Additionally, there's no (AFAIK) algorithmic way of doing it, you have to look it up; Photoshop, Illustrator, Quark, etc, have that ability, though, IIRC.

Comment: Yes, I tried Photoshop to get my values. I was able to get RGB values for a given CMYK value from the Color Picker, but could not find a way to fetch CMYK/RGB from a PMS value.

Comment: Hmm ... Well, since Pantone makes part of their money from the sale of the books, they probably frown on people putting the electronic equivalent into their software, at least without (insert adjective here) amounts of licensing fees.  Truthfully, Photoshop doesn't have much use for supporting PMS, but Illustrator, InDesign, Quark, etc definitely do.  I would pursue one of those options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.zedimage.com/pms-cmyk-hex.php